# Create Table from View - Oracle SQL SQL Error: ORA-01723: zero-length columns are not allowed

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a table from view with statement like

```
CREATE  TABLE NEW_TABLE AS
    SELECT *
    from VIEW
```

It is giving error message as below. It is not possible to create table from view (with Select * statement)?

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01723: zero-length columns are not allowed
01723. 00000 -  "zero-length columns are not allowed
```

Comment: I think you view has a 'NULL AS column_name' column.

Comment: @mehmetsahin - perhaps, but it is also possible that the view itself selects from an existing base table (or several) where the column is already `NULL` (in all rows). Selecting `null AS <column_name>` is not the only, or even the most likely, way to end up in that kind of situation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have this problem when `NULL` is specified for a column, but the type is not specified.  Arrgh!

You will need to look at the code.  This often happens when I use:

```
select '' as x
```

Because I think `''` should have the right type.

In any case, the solution is simple:

```
select cast(NULL as varchar2(255)),
       cast(NULL as number)
```

or whatever the type is.

You'll need to either change the view definition, or use a query with a subquery with explicit casts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! there was one null column in my view. I removed. It worked :)

Comment: Even if `''` was the right type (and even if Oracle followed the SQL Standard and differentiated between NULL and empty strings, which it sadly does not), you may still have the same problem... because an empty string has length zero. It is illegal to declare a column as data type `varchar2(0)`. Which is why `cast(null as varchar2(255))` (or whatever column length is most appropriate for the OP's application) is exactly the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Error >> "Zero length columns are not allowed "

I recently encountered the similar issue and in such cases I always google and come to stack overflow site for the solution but this time I didn't get the solution for my issue. I checked different other sites too but no help. I tried several ways but no luck. Finally my manager suggested me few tips and tricks and finally we were able to resolve this.

I am posting the steps below which I followed that time and resolve the issue.
So, I was getting the above error "Zero length columns are not allowed". When I checked the MV script, I found most of the columns having zero length, and I was not able to create the MV because of this.
This is how I fixed it:

1. Create a table with any name. For example `abc` using MV table structure.
2. Our MV was using force view as a source. So I created VW script using that table `abc` as a source like

   CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW xyz.VW
   (
   columns
   )
   as
   select * from abc;
3. now create MV script like below

   drop MV;
   create mv mv_name(
   columns
   )

   REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND

   WITH PRIMARY KEY

   AS

   select * from VW ;
4. EXECUTE the original VW script
5. now drop the table you created.

> > > 

1. Execute the table_script.sql   >> schema  XYZ
2. Execute FORCE VIEW script
3. Execute MATERIALIZED VIEW script
4. Execute FORCE VIEW original script
5. Execute Drop_table.txt

My manager helped me to resolve this issue . Thanks Ashish .

Regards

Niharika